# Do any migration tools work with SQL Server CE 4.0?

Tags: .net, sql-server, migration, sql-server-ce

I'm looking for a tool like FluentMigrator or Tarantino that will work with SQL CE. It appears that neither of those do.

Comment: I pulled down your fork, built and it worked great! Thanks for sharing.

Comment: Also pulled your fork, works great, thanks for that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MIgrator.NET is an opensource library.  I've used it to do migrations for SQL CE, but it could be that I've written the SQLCE driver myself.

Comment: You're right, it does indeed support CE according to the project site (I had overlooked that). However, I had tried to dump the schema of my existing DB to test it and it failed, so I had assumed it didn't support CE. I think it probably supports 3.5, but not 4.0. But it probably wouldn't be too hard to add a provider for 4.0.

Comment: MigratorDotNet had support for SQL CE 3.5 (though with a few bugs), but not 4.0. I have forked the project, updated it to 4.0 and fixed the bugs I've found. The project can be found here: https://bitbucket.org/ToddRopog/migratordotnet